# Stripe create a connected account doesn't allow a redirect uri?

Tags: stripe-payments

Users of my app can create a connected express account using an [accountlink](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create), the problem is the only 'redirect' url it allows is a valid http/https link (referred to as a return_url in the [accountlinks](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create)). The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) recommended setting up a dynamic link under step 2.4 - is this really the only way? The domain I own associated with my app is a google domain (rip) using google sites. I don't think I can add a universal link to a google sites website. How can I get users to redirect back to my app off the url I give stripe (return_url)?

Also, my first though was to set up a universal link with firebase dynamic links, but they are shutting down too (rip).

Comment: `return_url` of an Account Link only accepts HTTP/HTTPS link and universal link. URL in other format such as custom URL scheme is not supported.